# Correct way to assign 'Menu' button in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode5, uisplitviewcontroller

I have added a `UISplitViewController` to my storyboard in Xcode 5, but it doesn't have a navigation bar. Looking at an older project I did, the `UISplitViewController` shows a navigation bar.

In xcode 5, what is the correct way to use a `UISplitViewController` and show a `Menu` button when in portrait mode?

I have the delegate methods being called in my master view controller (The left/menu side) and understand that in the `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` method I need to use the `barButtonItem` to set the `menu` button. But where do I tell it to put it and how?

Should I add a `UINavigationController` to my detail/right view controller?

Thanks

Comment: just create iPad master-detail application example in XCode and take a look how it's done. Master and detail panels are embedded into navigation controllers there so they have navbars.

Comment: Good advice. I'll do that, thanks. When you drag a splitview into storyboard, the master has a nav controller but the detail doesn't.

Comment: Sorted it thanks. Using the Detail view as the splitview delegate was better.